# How can i recreate the YAST GUI in text file

Tags: linux, opensuse, rpm

I  have an OpenSUSE vm and want to list the applications installed.

I know i can do a RPM cmd and ls {PATH//: /} seems to return a long list although it is full of non-application libraries and guff.

**Attempts**

```
RPM -l;
ls {PATH//: /}; 
for d in ${PATH//:/ }/ ; do 
    for f in $d/* ; do  
        test -x $f && test -f $f && echo $f
    done
done
```

I noticed YAST GUI lays out exactly what i want - applications by category and with other metadata such as size and location.

How can i get this data via the cmd line so that i could query it programmatically?

i have tried `YAST -l` and that lists modules but not apps,. I can't see any other relevant options.

Answer (score 0):

> I noticed YAST GUI lays out exactly what i want - applications by
>   category and with other metadata such as size and location.

As root use YaST in command line. You can choose in Software Managment use the filter that you wanted, for example RPM Groups:

[image]

in Extras you can "Export Package List to File" a xml file will be created

Comment: Hey Thx. I'm not sure what the cmd line is to give me the list of applications by category? Above appears to be the non-gnome terminal interface, i want to get a list and pump it to a txt file for example?

Comment: Any idea how i can do this surely from cmd line, you are using GUI in above screenshot.

Comment: try just yast on a tty... you will see that! the GUI is different to this I put on the screenshot ahh the above screenshot is xterm there I typed yast (as root!) regards, maniat1k

Comment: i dont know what you are talking about sorry, baby steps please, im not competent in linux world. What is the cmd i write in the terminal to give me a definitive list of installed applications?

Comment: Read the answer `yast > Software Managment > filter RPM Groups`, regards, maniat1k

Comment: OK i needed '' around the phrases with spaces. And this brings up the GUI as i mentioned, how do i get the list of applications in a text file by category? This doesnt appear to solve the issue

Comment: in Extras you can "Export Package List to File" a xml file will be created . - I'm adding this to the answer.

Comment: I dont understand if the misunderstanding is on my or your side but this doesn't solve my issue. My original Q: 'How can i get this data via the cmd line so that i could query it programmatically?' all your answers require the Yast UI to be navigated through.  Can you send the cmd that will achieve this, dont use a UI, I cant script navigation through the UI. As i mentioned, dont assume i know how to do the above programatically, please explain what 'in extras' means - how do i do this as part of a script that is fired and writes a file of applications without any interaction.

Answer (score 0):

You can query the software repository with `zypper` using the `se` search command

```
zypper se <app name>
```

or with the info command

```
zypper info <app name>
```

You can request to have an XML formated output with the `--xmlout` parameter.

I recommend you to read the [OpenSuSE documentation on zypper](https://fr.opensuse.org/SDB:Zypper_usage_11.3#Querying)

Some example taken from the link above :

```
# zypper se sqlite

Reading installed packages...

S | Name                     | Summary                                                        | Type
--+--------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------
  | libapr-util1-dbd-sqlite3 | DBD driver for SQLite 3                                        | package
i | libgda-3_0-sqlite        | Sqlite Provider for GNU Data Access (GDA)                      | package
  | libqt4-sql-sqlite        | Qt 4 sqlite plugin                                             | package
i | libsqlite3-0             | Shared libraries for the Embeddable SQL Database Engine        | package
  | libsqlite3-0-32bit       | Shared libraries for the Embeddable SQL Database Engine        | package
  | mediatomb-sqlite         | UPnP AV MediaServer                                            | package
i | mono-data-sqlite         | Database connectivity for Mono                                 | package
  | pdns-backend-sqlite2     | SQLite 2 backend for pdns                                      | package


--------------

# zypper info amarok

Reading installed packages...


Information for package amarok:

Repository: Packman 11.1
Name: amarok
Version: 1.4.9.1-103.pm.1
Arch: x86_64
Vendor: packman.links2linux.de
Installed: Yes
Status: up-to-date
Installed Size: 12.1 M
Summary: Media Player for KDE
Description:
Amarok is a media player for all kinds of media, supported by aRts, GStreamer
or Xine (depending on the packages you install). This includes MP3, Ogg
Vorbis, audio CDs and streams.
It also supports audio effects of all kinds that are provided by aRts.
Playlists can be stored in .m3u or .pls files.
```

Comment: great thx. I actually need a definitive list of the applications so i can use the above command to get more info on each, any idea how i can do that?